# Understanding Header and Detail tables

Tags: sql, database-design, database-normalization

I have seen this in various DB but I will use the most recent example.
In the AdventurWorks2012 DB, there are

- PurchaseOrderHeader
- PurchaseOrderDetail

and

- SalesOrderHeader
- SalesOrderDetail

I am trying to understand the concept of why you would have this setup when you can put all that information in one table instead of two.  Sorry for my lack of knowledge on this type of setup.  I want to make sure when I create new tables, I am wondering with this type of design, how this would work similar to what I may incorporate to capture Data Entry into a table using Header and Detail and the reason why.

e.g.

1. Current Date
2. Current Month
3. Current Fiscal Year
4. Company ID
5. Revision Number
6. Service Product 1 Amount
7. Service Product 2 Amount
8. Service Product 3 Amount
9. Service Product 4 Amount
10. Service Product 5 Amount
11. Total Amount (Sum Items 6-10 above)
12. Certification Date
13. Certification Officer
14. Submission Date

Hope my question is clear.

======================

Edited for detailed example of using Header/Detail setup via my response to  @Szymon

In my above example, to layout it out as a Header/Detail setup. When a record is submitted, it generates an ID So my Header Table would look like:

Header Table

1, '11/13/13',11,2013,'000001',0,10.00,'11/12/13','President','Chuck','11/12/13'

then in my Detail Table it would generate an ID also but use the previous Record as a FK and it would look like this... 1 (New ID), 1 (FK of Header Table previously), 2 (As Service Product 1), 2 (As Service Product 2), 2 (As Service Product 3), 2 (As Service Product 4), 2 (As Service Product 5)

Detail Table

1,1,2.00,2.00,2.00,2.00,2.00

==================================================

Revised Again:  To provide a better follow up example.

WKS_Header Table: (PK is WKS_Header_ID)

```
WKS_Header_ID [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Company_ID [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
Current_Date [DateTime] NOT NULL, 
Current_Month [int] NOT NULL, 
Current_Fiscal_Year [int] NOT NULL,
Revision_Number [int] NOT NULL,
Worksheet_ID [varchar] (13) NOT NULL,
Total_Amt [money] NOT NULL,
Certification_Date [DateTime] NOT NULL,
Certification_Officer [varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
Submission_Date [DateTime] NOT NULL
```

Sample Records of WKS_Header Table:

```
1,'000001','11/5/13',11,2013,0,'0000001111300',20.00,'11/1/13','Chuck','11/2/13'
2,'000001','11/7/13',11,2013,1,'0000001111301',10.00,'11/4/13','Chuck','11/5/13'
3,'000500','11/10/13',11,2013,0,'0005001111300',50.00,'11/5/13','Bob','11/7/13'
```

WKS_LineItems Table: (PK is WKS_LineItems_ID)

```
WKS_LineItems_ID [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
LineItem_Description [varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
Create_User_ID [varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
Create_Date [datetime] NOT NULL,
Modify_User_ID [varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
Modify_Date [datetime] NOT NULL
```

Sample of WKS_LineItems Table

```
1,'Service Product Widget A Amount','Admin','10/1/13',Null,Null
2,'Service Product Widget B Amount','Admin','10/1/13',Null,Null
3,'Service Product Widget C Amount','Admin','10/1/13',Null,Null
4,'Service Product Widget D Amount','Admin','10/1/13',Null,Null
5,'Service Product Widget E Amount','Admin','10/1/13',Null,Null
6,'Final Total Widgets Amount','Admin','10/1/13',Null,Null
```

WKS_Details Table: (PK is WKS_Details_ID, FK is WKS_Header_ID from WKS_Header Table)

```
WKS_Details_ID IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
WKS_Header_ID [int] NOT NULL,
WKS_LineItems_ID [int] NOT NULL,
WKS_Amount [decimal] (18,2) NOT NULL,
Create_User_ID [varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
Create_Date [datetime] NOT NULL
```

Sample Of WKS_Details Table

```
1,1,1,4.00,'Chuck','11/5/13'
2,1,2,0.00,'Chuck','11/5/13'
3,1,3,0.00,'Chuck','11/5/13'
4,1,4,5.00,'Chuck','11/5/13'
5,1,5,11.00,'Chuck','11/5/13'
6,1,6,20.00,'Chuck','11/5/13'
7,2,1,0.00,'Chuck','11/7/13'
8,2,2,0.00,'Chuck','11/7/13'
9,2,3,0.00,'Chuck','11/7/13'
10,2,4,0.00,'Chuck','11/7/13'
11,2,5,0.00,'Chuck','11/7/13'
12,2,6,10.00,'Chuck','11/7/13'
13,3,1,10.00,'Bob','11/10/13'
14,3,2,10.00,'Bob','11/10/13'
15,3,3,10.00,'Bob','11/10/13'
16,3,4,10.00,'Bob','11/10/13'
17,3,5,10.00,'Bob','11/10/13'
18,3,6,50.00,'Bob','11/10/13'
```

Scenario:
Input information from a Form.  It creates 3 records in the WKS_Header Table with associated detail records into WKS_Details table.

Record ID 1 is an original submission, then that user needs to revise the numbers.  That user inputs another record.  That is Record ID 2, a revised submission to supersede Record ID 1.
Record ID 3 is an original submission.

Do I have this normalized correctly?

Comment: It would help a lot if you described the structures of these tables, so that those of us not immediately familiar with the pattern would be able to analyze it. At a guess, I'd say there might be a one-to-many relationship between the "Header" and "Detail" tables, such that you'd have one "Detail" entry per line item in an order, but without seeing at least column names and types for both tables, it's impossible to say anything with certainty.

Comment: It does; @Szymon's answer is exactly correct.

Comment: @CharlesBernardes: Your revision looks like you're adding a completely different question. Your original question was about header/details tables such as orders, whereas your revision seems to be about history/revision tables and as such completely muddies the water. Better to remove the addition and ask a separate question. What is WKS?

Answer (score 9):

This type of relationship is called one-to-many relationship. It is used when there is one parent record and multiple child records. You use that kind of relationship to [normalise data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

In case of a purchase order, you have one header which describes the order, e.g. order number and date. There's only one set of this information for an order.

Then there's multiple line items, each with its own item name, quantity and price. There's many items for each table.

If you were to create only one table, you would have to repeat the information from the invoice header for each item. You would have the same order date and number repeated over as many rows as you have items.

This is bad for a few reasons, among them:

- You have redundant data that takes unnecessary space and are hard to maintain (e.g you have to update multiple records if you want to update one information in the header).
- Querying the table is more complex, e.g. when you want to display a list of order headers, you would have to use `DISTINCT`.
- The structure is not standard (not normalised) and difficult to read for other people who expect a standard approach to database design.

Comment: In my above example, to layout it out as a Header/Detail setup.
When a record is submitted, it generates an ID
So my Header Table would look like:

Comment: You asked a question seeking clarification of using 2 tables so I have given this. Is there anything more you'd like?

Comment: In my above example, to layout it out as a Header/Detail setup.
When a record is submitted, it generates an ID
So my Header Table would look like:
    1, '11/13/13',11,2013,'000001',0,10.00,'11/12/13','President','Chuck','11/12/13'

then in my Detail Table it would generate an ID also but use the previous Record as a FK and it would look like this...

    1 (New ID),
    1 (FK of Header Table previously),
    2 (As Service Product 1),
    2 (As Service Product 2),
    2 (As Service Product 3),
    2 (As Service Product 4),
    2 (As Service Product 5)

Comment: I laid out my response for better viewing on my original post.  Thanks.

Comment: thoughts on this again.  See my edit to original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is done as a process of normalisation so that it reduces redundant data.

see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878

Answer (score 0):

Along with Szymon's answer, I'd like to point out a few more advantages of using header/details tables

1. The number of lines in the order (ie details table) is not defined. Thus one can have an order with one line or a hundred lines. In the example given, one is limited to five lines only.
2. Extracting data regarding the lines is very easy as each line exists on its own. If there is a query to find out in which order a given part exists, the header/details structure makes this very easy to do, whereas a single table means that the query has to check field1, field2, field3, etc. Not so simple.

Comment: I edited again on my original post.  Is this a better example of a layout?

Answer (score 0):

Header and Detail table concept is used to perform normalization in SQL. Normalization is the process of reducing data redundancy. We can not remove data redundancy. But we can reduce data redundancy. Data redundancy is duplicating the items. There are some issues with data redundancy as follows.
If a table is not properly normalized and have data redundancy then it will not only eat up extra memory space. But will also make it difficult to handle and update the database, without facing data loss. Insertion, Updation and Deletion Anamolies are very frequent if database is not normalized.

You can refer those links to learn normalization.

https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html